# Drupal 6 db_query issue retrieving utf8 characters

Tags: utf-8, drupal-6

I have a very weird problem with drupal 6 concerning retrieving characters that are in the UTF8 character set. Interesting it seems it is only drupal API that is having the problem with correctly retrieving the data; when I directly get the data using mysqli and also from the command line, everything seems to be OK.

The database and table is set to the correct charset and collation as shown below:

```
    mysql> show variables like "collation_%";
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show variables like "char_%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I retrieve the data from the command line, everything seems to be OK.

```
   mysql> select id, name from web_gfo_article_type;
   | 294 | ДОСЛОВНО                                                      |
   | 295 | EXAMEN                                                        |
   | 296 | REVISIÓN                                                      |
```

In one of my custom drupal modules am retrieving the same data using drupal API (db_query) and using the direct approach, using mysqli.

Direct approach:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_db_user_name", "my_db_password", "my_db_name");
$r = $mysqli->query("select id, name from web_gfo_article_type");

while ($row = $r->fetch_object()) {
    print('<br/>' . $row->id . ' ' . $row->name);
}
```

Result of direct approach:

```
294 ДОСЛОВНО
295 EXAMEN
296 REVISIÓN
```

Using drupal db API:

```
$r = db_query("select id, name from web_gfo_article_type");

while ($row = db_fetch_object($r)) {
    print('<br/>' . $row->id . ' ' . $row->name);
}
```

Result of drupal db API call:

```
294 Ð”ÐžÐ¡Ð›ÐžÐ’ÐÐž
295 EXAMEN
296 REVISIÃ“N
```

As you can clearly see, there is something terribly wrong with how drupal db API is retrieving the data, which is causing the UTF data to be munched up when presented. All the above result is being shown in a HTML page where the meta header information has been correctly set i.e

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Can someone point me in the right direction as to what could be happening and what am doing wrong. Much appreciated.

Comment: How is your `settings.php` file configured? You have a `$db_url` variable, how does it look like? Of course we don't need the credentials, just interested in the format. Is it like this `$db_url = 'mysqli://username:password@localhost/databasename';`?

Comment: Max - Yep, my db url is like you have indicated: $db_url = 'mysqli://mydbusername:mydbpassword@localhost/mydbname';

Comment: Strange, because in this case Drupal functions (`db_query`, `db_fetch_object`) are just wrappers around the `mysqli` functions in PHP. And those seem to be returning the correct results...

Comment: It's probably a long shot but can you put the table names in curly brackets like this and see what you get: `$r = db_query("select id, name from {web_gfo_article_type}");`

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure, the .module-file(?) where you wrote the query is using utf-8?